# Heap's algorithm - integer permutation

Tags: java, array, combinatorics

Integer permutation using [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm):

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class IntegerPermutation {

    private static void swap(Integer[] integerArray, int i, int j) {
        Integer temp = integerArray[i];
        integerArray[i] = integerArray[j];
        integerArray[j] = temp;
    }

    private static void permutationHelper(Integer[] integerArray,
            int currentPosition) {

        if (currentPosition == 1) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integerArray));
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < currentPosition; i++) {
                permutation(integerArray, currentPosition - 1);

                if (currentPosition % 2 == 0) {
                    swap(integerArray, i, currentPosition - 1);
                } else {
                    swap(integerArray, 0, currentPosition - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void permutation(Integer[] integerArray, int lengthOfTheArray) {
        permutationHelper(integerArray, lengthOfTheArray);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] a = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        IntegerPermutation.permutation(a, a.length);
    }
}
```

Can you please critique my code and provide your thoughts on where I should improve my code?

Answer (score 4):

#### `permutation` -> `permutationHelper` -> `permutation` -> ...

As @MartinR pointed out,
the `permutation` and `permutationHelper` functions calling each other are confusing.
In fact, `permutation` is actually pointless,
as it does nothing but call `permutationHelper`.

To give `permutation` some purpose,
you could do this:

- Make `permutationHelper` call itself instead of `permutation`
- Drop the array length parameter from `permutation`: it can derive it from the array it receives, and pass that to `permutationHelper`

#### Why `Integer[]` instead of `int[]` ?

In the posted program, there's really no need for `Integer` objects.
You can work with `int[]`, which is slightly lighter.

#### Code duplication

There are several duplicated elements in this code:

> ```
> permutation(integerArray, currentPosition - 1);
>
> if (currentPosition % 2 == 0) {
>     swap(integerArray, i, currentPosition - 1);
> } else {
>     swap(integerArray, 0, currentPosition - 1);
> }
> ```

First of all, the `currentPosition - 1` is duplicated.
It would be good to store it in a local variable.

Secondly, `swap` is called with almost the same parameters, except one.
This could be expressed more compactly using a ternary operator.

```
int nextPosition = currentPosition - 1;
permutation(integerArray, nextPosition);
swap(integerArray, currentPosition % 2 == 0 ? i : 0, nextPosition);
```

#### Initializing arrays

A simpler way to initialize arrays is using `{ ... }`, like this:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Comment: I am not a Java expert, but isn't `Integer[] a = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 };` in the original code already the type of initialization which you are suggesting in your last point?

Comment: I forgot to edit after a copy-paste. Fixed now, thanks!

Comment: _"there's really **no** need for Integer"_, is it?

Answer (score 3):

One thing I noticed is that `permutation()` calls `permutationHelper()`
with exactly the same arguments. So you don't need two separate methods
but just

```
public static void permutation(Integer[] integerArray,
        int currentPosition) { ... }
```

which calls itself recursively.